# Codename – language DataPicker Calendar

Tags: codenameone

How change or configure default localize language for a DataPicker “com.codename1.ui.Calendar”

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> To localize strings for month names use the values "Calendar.Month" using the 3 first characters of the month name in the resource localization e.g. "Calendar.Jan", "Calendar.Feb" etc...
> To localize strings for day names use the values "Calendar.Day" in the resource localization e.g. "Calendar.Sunday", "Calendar.Monday" etc...

From https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Calendar.html

When we say localize we mean a resource bundle: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/plaf/UIManager.html#setBundle-java.util.Map-